# Local Service and Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-service

As I know, local service run in the same process as the launching activity.
Is that means if service terminated by the OS unexpectedly, activity also will terminated ?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity won't be affected when the service crashes. Only when the application process crashes, the local service and the activity will be terminated. 
After the application process is recovered, your activity will start up again from the beginning and the local service will be bound with your activity.